# Liquid dielectrics, having polar molecules(such as water), always have dielectric constants that decreases with increasing temperature. why?

Tags: dielectric

liquid dielectrics having polar molecules (such as water) always have dielectric constants that decreases with increasing temperature. what will be the explanation for that scenario? why is that happen? what will be the possible example for that

Answer (score 2):

The greater the alignment of the polar molecules the greater is the dielectric constant. Thermal agitation reduces the "average" alignment of the polar molecules in an electric field.

So an increase in the temperature (greater thermal agitation) will reduce the dielectric constant (reduce the average alignment of the polar molecules).

However when there is a phase change from solid (harder to change alignment of polar molecules in the presence of an electric field) to liquid (easier to change alignment) the dielectric constant can increase.

Comment: You might also explain the role of Boltzmann factors:  $\exp (-pE/kT)$